# Keep unique values of array, preserving order, retaining last occurrence of each

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array(0, 3, 4, 3, 6);
```

And I want to filter out doubles, but keep the **last** result

`array_unique` gives me 0, 3, 4, 6.. but I need it to give 0, 4, 3, 6  (so it keeps the last 3, instead of the first)

Comment: 1) Implement your own function, or 2) reverse the array before and after.

Comment: @deceze too bad there's no `array_reduce_right()` :)

Comment: @Jack https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php :-3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just reverse it :

```
// Reverse an array, starting backwards
function array_unique_end($array)
{
  return array_reverse(array_unique(array_reverse($array)));
}
```

That however will not be very performant. You might be better off creating your own implementation

Comment: +1 . but you are missing an s in `array_reverse` function. :)

Comment: You can also use this to keep the keys like `array_unique()` does:
    function array_unique_right($array)
     {
       return array_reverse(array_unique(array_reverse($array, true)), true);
     }
Nice job, Ven!

Answer (score 3):

This would be one way, traversing the array backwards:

```
$arr = array(0, 3, 4, 3, 6);

$res = array();
for ($i = count($arr) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        $item = $arr[$i];

        if (!isset($res[$item])) {
                $res = array($item => $item) + $res; // unshift
        }
}
print_r(array_values($res));
```

I've made a trade off between speed and memory by using an intermediate map, so that `isset()` can be used, from which the values (or keys) can be stripped to form the final result.

**Update**

It outperforms the double `array_reverse()` and `array_unique()` approach as the array becomes larger, so it's not that bad after all :)

Comment: @arnaud576875 https://gist.github.com/datibbaw/260772aef07957393092 - the benchmark code itself is work in progress ;-)